# How to stagger multiple animation delays in Sass?

Tags: css, for-loop, sass

I was wondering how I can calculate two animation delays (fade in and fade out) by using a for loop in Sass.

Came up with the following, but doesn't know how to calc the second animation delay.

```
@for $i from 1 through 2 {
    .text:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-delay: ($i * 0.5s), 4s;
    }
}
```

I would like to do the same for the fade in, so each text element will be slightly stagger.

Already tried something like this, but with no result.

```
@for $i from 1 through 2 {
    .text:nth-child(#{$i, $a}) {
        animation-delay: ($i * 0.5s), ($a * 0.5s);
    }
}
```

And how can I use the last delay to start another delay of another animation?

Comment: Can this help you? https://glennmccomb.com/articles/creating-smooth-sequential-animations-with-sass/

Comment: Great resource, only it isn't clear enough how I can use two delays and calculate also the second one.

Comment: Can you post an example of the ideal output you'd like?

Comment: Can you post the entire animation code block? Name, Delay, Duration, etc. That would help. My guess would be that you need to add the duration of the first animation to the start of the second. `$i * 0.5s, ($i *0.5s)+duration1s`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

**The easy version**

That said, the basic idea is to do the "in" and "out" animations as percentages of the same animation function. In this case the `build in = 25%`, `static = 50%`, and `build out = 25%`.

Then your duration controls how long each part takes to complete. In this case 2 seconds.

Next, the delay (calculated as part of the loop) offsets the animation. You could also multiply the duration in the loop to completely stagger the animation.

```
$timeOffset: 0.5s;
$aniLength: 2s;
// 0.5s in, 1s solid, 0.5s out = 2sec

.item {
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: $aniLength;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@for $i from 1 through 20 {
    .item:nth-child(#{$i}){
        // units are in the variable so SCSS just does math
        animation-delay: $i * $timeOffset;
    }
}

@keyframes animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translatex(100%);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translatex(-100%);
    }
}
```

Here's a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/XwxjRM) since SO doesn't parse SCSS in the code sandbox available here.

**More complex version with multiple delays**

Your second example didn't work because you were building an odd selector in your `nth-child` code while using an undefined variable.

Also, you can do pretty complex math for each iteration. Just remember concepts like Order of Operations.

The correct way to specify two different delay values is like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 20 {
        // the hash forces SCSS to create a string
    .item:nth-child(#{$i}){
        // you need to use $i for BOTH since its the only defined increment
        animation-delay: $i * $timeOffset, $i * $timeOffset + $aniLength;
        // delay #1 = iteration * 0.5s, delay #2 = iteration * 0.5s + 2s (run at end of animation plus the offset)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set @if, @for, @each and @while in SCSS file. Refer [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/nt6p9hs2/29/) for fade out animation base on for loops.

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .div-wrapper {
     div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transition: all $i/3 +s;
      transition-delay: $i/3 +s;
    }
   }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/nt6p9hs2/29/

Refernce: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while